# Seeking Example CLIP Model Code Allowing Me to Use a Pretrained Model and Go Directly to Inference Without any Additional Training

Tags: nlp, computer-vision, language-model

I have been endlessly searching for open-source code (including from OpenAI themselves) which would allow me to take a pretrained CLIP model image encoder (e.g., the ViT B/32) and then solely based on the weights from the pretrained image encoder directly attempt to infer either a corresponding text description "label" from an image I feed the encoder, or vice-versa, will allow me to provide it a prompt after which it will return an image based on that prompt.

Is this even possible without taking some additional dataset of image-text pairs to further train the pretrained CLIP image encoder on?  All the code examples I have come across provide you the pretrained image encoder - but then require you to do MORE training using an extra dataset that (presumably) was never used during pretraining. Some of these code examples then allow you to provide a text prompt, in response to which the model will return an image (from the dataset you fed it during the training process) which aligns with your prompt.

I.e., I don't want to do any extra training. I just want the pretrained image encoder, then provide that image encoder with 1 image, and then have it return to me a matching text description of it. Alternatively, provide the pretrained (not re-trained) image encoder with a text prompt, and have it return to me an image that it was originally pretrained on (or at least an image that it was not re-trained on).

Some examples of code that **ARE NOT** what I am looking for (although very well done) include the following:

https://github.com/moein-shariatnia/OpenAI-CLIP/blob/master/.ipynb_checkpoints/OpenAI%20CLIP%20Simple%20Implementation-checkpoint.ipynb

https://towardsdatascience.com/quick-fire-guide-to-multi-modal-ml-with-openais-clip-2dad7e398ac0

https://colab.research.google.com/github/openai/CLIP/blob/main/notebooks/Interacting_with_CLIP.ipynb

Thank you.

Comment: I think what you are looking for are text-to-image models https://huggingface.co/tasks/image-to-text. CLIP has another functionality. You can use the model to convert a text prompt into an embedding and compare that embedding to embeddings of images to find similar ones.